# Solution of local Cauchy Problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given this Cauchy Problem:

[image]

My question is: How does one exactly see there in the end that $\varphi$ solves the problem (8.1.4)?

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question; substituting the ansatz $u = e^{i \omega t} \varphi$ into the PDE (4.1.1) where $g = \lvert u \rvert^{\alpha} u$ yields the equation (8.1.4). For the ansatz to work, it must be that $\varphi$ solves (8.1.4).

Comment: What happend to the exponential term though?

Comment: It cancels. I suggest you compute it out.